# How to know if a place exists at a location via google maps on PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinates, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Is it possible to confirm if a place name exists for a specified coordinates via PHP?

In other words, is it possible to make a request to google maps indicating the place name and their coordinates and receive something if it exists or nothing if the place don't exists at the specified coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to search for a place by name in a specific vicinity and you'll get a bunch of results back. It'll be up to you to compare those results to the search term though and decide whether the match is close enough to consider it a duplicate/existing. There's hardly a simple true/false answer for things as rather vague as place names and coordinates.

Comment: Hmm, but if i have the exact coordinates and name of the place, I just need to make a request for the coordinates and verify if the place name exists in the results right?

Comment: What are "exact coordinates"? Coordinates can be exact down to a millimeter. One "place" is usually at least several dozens square feet in area. How can you guarantee Google and you have exactly the same coordinates at exactly the same resolution? There will always be some fuzziness. Place names can also be spelled in all sorts of different ways, there's also some fuzziness there.

Comment: By "exact coordinates" I want to say the coordinates received from a Google Maps API for Javascript. Could they be different when received by Javascript and by PHP?

Comment: 123.4567 is accurate to about 11m. 123.45678 is accurate to about 1m. If you pick a place on a Google map, it may give you coordinates with 6 or more digits after the decimal place. That's highly accurate. But who knows with what accuracy the place coordinates were entered into Google's Place database? For a building a few hundred square meters in area, it makes a real difference whether you pick a highly accurate spot in the southwest corner or a less accurate spot in the northeast corner. It might indicate a different place, or it mightn't. It's *fuzzy*.

Comment: Hmm, right. But my intention is just to confirm that what was inserted via javascript was not modified before reach the server. So, I belive it should work =). I will try it later.